# How to open an element, such as a picture, in an iframe on a Google Books webpage (or the iframe itself), in a new tab?

Tags: google-books, iframe

Google Books pages seem to have a resistance against opening the content of their iframe in a new window or tab. Right-clicking in the iframe, or particularly on a picture in the iframe, does not work. It will not allow it.

Is there a workaround to this?

I am using Opera but I suppose this is something involving all browsers.

Example - [this URL](https://books.google.be/books?id=rOEzDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=archangel+of+japanese+people&source=bl&ots=z7MlqeQB-L&sig=lOKrt1O_zmjCXQaXZF1UcI9oZgQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwih_bqj3rjXAhVIoqQKHd5lAVAQ6AEIVzAN#v=onepage&q=archangel%20of%20japanese%20people&f=false) and you scroll a bit up to page 33 to see a picture.

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished with the CSS rule

```
user-select: none;
```

Note that Opera uses "-webkit-user-select" because this CSS is still experimental.

Extensions like RightToClick on Firefox override this. A userscript that overrides this CSS rule would also work.